# how to convert the easting and northing to a point and saved in a feature class in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, gps

I write a program to decode the message from the GPS device to get the easting and northing , but I don't know how to convert the easting and northing to a point and saved in a feature class in ArcMap.

Do anyone have similar experience ?

Regards
Gary Sham

Answer (score 4):

If you have the data in a table defined as a X and Y coordinate its beyond easy. All you do is load that table into your ArcMap instance; then right click that table in your Catalog view and you will see the option to build the Point from X/Y.
 Now if you are not using ArcGIS 10 you can refer to this write-up from ESRI for details [HowTo:  Import XY data tables to ArcMap and convert the data to a shapefile](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27589).